# How to move content placeholders on a slide with same name in vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, placeholder

i want to move 3 placeholders with same name "Content Placeholder 7". When i write the code to select it selects the original placeholder and ignore the rest. I also want to move the two arrows little upwards.

[image]

Here is the code i have been writing: I might be writing the shape names incorrectly, please correct if wrong.

```
Sub Export_Range()

    Dim pp As New PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppapp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    Dim intTableRows As Integer, intTableCols As Integer

        Sheet2.Columns("B:C").ClearContents
        First = Sheet1.Range("J3").Value
        Last = Sheet1.Range("K3").Value
            
            For j = First To Last

                With ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes.Range(Array("Content Placeholder 7", "Arrow:Left 12", "Arrow:Left 13"))
                    .Top = 150
                End With
End Sub
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: If you have different shapes with the same name, it will select the first one it finds (presumably the one with the lowest index). You need to change the names or work with indexes (i.e. loop with `i` as index and check if the name matches). Reg. arrows, you need to check the names: I might be wrong, but I see a space after the colon in the image you provided. You also need a `Next j` at the end of your loop

Comment: This is the result of lazy designer syndrome: copying and pasting placeholders on the layouts instead of creating each from scratch. This problem can also cause content rotation among the placeholders if a layout is changed, then changed back. In addition to using the index to distinguish them, you can use their position. While you're manipulating them, renaming them is also a good idea.